# Could we become the universe?

Tags: science-based, universe

First question ever here. This is not my first language so sorry for any mistake. How could a species become the Universe itself, as in controlling every single particle and permeating every form of energy, every scalar field, to become a single entity, a One in a certain way? This species would need to overcome the expansion of the universe for a start?

Comment: Welcome to the site J-p Bélanger, when you have a few minutes, please take the [tour] and read up in our [help] about how we work: [ask]. I like the question, but can't guarantee people won't try to close it as too broad, or unclear what you are asking. +1

Comment: _Long after the beginning..., Man became God._    I also like the question a lot but for once I am completely stumped.  Looking forward to reading how other members approach this ultimate task.

Comment: As we understand physics it's impossible to do what you want.  The [uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) means you cannot even control a single particle in an absolute sense, and this principle is very, very deeply woven into the way physics works.

Comment: @StephenG,there is no hard-science tag on this question, so we are allowed to hypothesize the unlikely but not-impossible possibility that parts of our current scientific understanding is completely wrong.  It is not at all unusual in science fiction to have characters discover a previously unseen order beneath the apparent chaos.  The uncertainty principle would definitely wreck the OP's plans for universal domination, but I would hate to see it get in the way of some cool speculation here in the forum.

Comment: @HenryTaylor Absolutley agree, someone once said "never let the facts get in the way of a good story", possibly Richard Nixon, not sure.

Comment: @HenryTaylor So the science-based tag just means ignore all fundamental principles and make up garbage ?

Comment: @StephenG.  You are correct and I am wrong.  I thought that science-based offered some latitude which is why we had a hard-science tag; but I just went and read the descriptions of both and I am mistaken.  Sorry for stepping on your absolutely valid assertion.  
It is a shame because I an halfway through typing an answer that Nixon would have loved.  Guess I will copy it to a notepad for later use.  Perhaps the original poster can edit the question to allow for some particles to remain independent.  Either that or remove the science-based tag.  
As always, thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: Given that this species must exist within the universe and are likely still composed of particles, I think we’re going to run into a Gödel-style problem where they’d then need to control themselves using particles which are in turn part of the larger universe as well, which would in turn need to be controlled.

Comment: @StephenG -- you can completely determine the quantum state of a system, the uncertainty principle is only a limitation on physical control if you believe there is more to a system than its quantum state, i.e. you believe in a [hidden variables interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden-variable_theory) where there is some objective truth about a particle's position and momentum simultaneously and we just can't know/control it.

Comment: As these comments are probably going to rise into a philosophical debate well above my scientific skill level, I have gone ahead and posted my admittedly faulty answer.  It does not live up to the science-based tag requirements, so I may deservedly loose a few points to down votes.  I like the answer though, so I am willing to pay the penalty.  If it gets too expensive, I will delete it.

Comment: It's always been [Wankershim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LostGanERWk).

Comment: You can't, simply because: a _species_ cannot be _one entity_, unless it is composed of just one individual, at which point it is no longer a viable species by itself, but a mutation of some other species. Now, assuming the species has become a hive mind, so that there are no individuals or personalities, so that it can said to be one person. Leaving aside reproductive issues (they manage, somehow), is it distinct from other species? If yes, then other species exist in the universe, so there is something else in the universe that is not that species; ergo, it cannot be the universe. contd...

Comment: Conversely, if no other species exists, that is distinct from the species under observation, then it _may_ be the universe, but is it still a species, i.e., distinct from some other living organism?

Answer (score 3):

The universe can become One, but not without great loss.  What you are describing is the subjugation and absorption of ever individual intelligence everywhere.  The vast majority of the universe's matter wouldn't care that it is being re-purposed; but for that precious fraction of a fraction of a percentage which is intelligence...

**you are describing an Apocalypse.**

Which leads to the answer that I would offer here.

The ascension of everything into a single universal mind begins with a grey goo scenario.  An advanced technological race, which has already mastered FTL, creates a new species of nanites, microscopic self-replicating robots which can adapt to a variety of tasks and purposes.  Those nanites quickly get out of control, consuming their creators and their original home planet to create a massive swarm which is ruled by a singular unified AI.

When one of the creator's FTL ships return to the home world, the AI takes it over and uses it to start colonizing other worlds.  Soon it is building a fleet of FTL ships and spreading out exponentially over all that exists.

As for the bigger challenges, such as the expanding universe, information-speed-limits and the uncertainty principle, those are challenges for the universal mind to solve.  As its' swarm grows to encompass the vast majority of the mass in the universe, it's collective conscious will need to grow proportionally.  Perhaps along the way, it will find solutions to the problems we can only loosely define.

It may never encompass everything, but once it commands more than half of all that is, no other force in the universe can oppose it; so its less than total omnipresence and omni-essence will be an academic distinction at best.  In all functional definitions, it will BE the universe.

Answer (score 3):

Isaac Asimov tackled that challenge in his Foundation series. A tool you use frequently becomes part of your body ... think of crutches or glasses or pacemakers. The more instrumented those tools — pacemakers, prosthetic limbs, etc — the more they are extensions of self. But there’s also a speed-of-thought aspect. A being that thinks slowly may have its thoughts encoded in slow-to-respond systems. Now take all that to logical extreme: all matter becoming connected by manipulable forces, where gravity extends over infinite distance. All matter gets organized into the body of a single slow-thinking entity. Entire planet ecologies may be considered individual neurons at that scale.

Modern physics suggests a problem with this... The system will break down (the entity will fragment and/or die) as universal inflation continues, unless the entity is able to control dark energy (whatever that turns out to be) to reverse the Big Bang. But if you account for that in your story, it’s a viable concept.

You’ll also need to assume that the entity has solved the quantum gravity problem and discovered some way to eliminate Heisenberg uncertainty in its manipulation of energy. Without that, the entity will only be the entire *macroscopic* universe, not subatomic.